# Embedding scripting language for debugging purposes

Tags: c++, debugging, scripting, gdb

I would like to embed a scripting language(js, python, perl, even php, anything that's easy to use) in an OpenGL C++ application. I'd like to do this in order to be able to do things like:

- print values of various C++ class members at runtime
- cause interrupts that would wake up gdb at runtime
- after I find a bug I'd like to write a small script oneliner to replicate it

I'm pretty sure this won't be easy. I want to ask whether this is a good/bad idea, and if it's worth the effort.

## Example usecase

Let's suppose I rotate a line until it collides something and my collision detection has some SIGSEGV which occurs upon collision. I print out all the angles, find out which one was the one before the SIGSEGV and I write a small python thingie which displays some values so I can figure out what went wrong etc.

I guess basically What I'm trying to do is to avoid gdb and uhm.. I'd like if the program blows to have a way to check things in Python instead.

It's not that I don't like gdb, it's that I don't like the limited commands it has..

**UPDATE:** GDB can now be extended [with Python](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Python.html#Python) out of the box. That solves a lot of the limitations of [canned sequences of commands](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Sequences.html#Sequences).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that for the purpose of debugging embedding a scripting language is a good idea. It's definitely possible, but for everything that you'd want to be able to access from the scripting language, you would have to provide some interface, since there's -- to the best of my knowledge at least -- no way to directly call C++ or read C++ data structures from a scripting language. I'd suggest you learn gdb or look for gdb frontends if you don't want to use gdb directly. I've used [ddd](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/) and found it quite useful. The gdb frontend of [Eclipse CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) is usable, too. Using a debugger gives you more flexibility, since the debugger knows about C++ and its data structures and thus allows you to inspect anything at runtime, without having to manually write much support code for that.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: You can print all those out using GDB quite easily. Once in GDB you might want to try what "*help data*" shows.

Which IDE do you use? You might want to try the cross-platform IDE Code::Blocks, which interfaces GDB quite neatly.

If you want to interface with another language, you might want to have a look on "Lua". It is very easy to learn.
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lua_%28programming_language%29

> Lua is intended to be embedded into other applications, and accordingly it provides a robust, easy-to-use C API. The API is divided into two parts: the Lua core and the Lua auxiliary library.

This works well with C++, too, of course.

Comment: I understand what you mean. GDB is simple to use for simple stuff, and I know how to use it but I'd like more control. I don't use an IDE exactly because of that. I intend to build a console inside the application I'm writing in order to be able to query things and see values in there. I will consider your suggestion with Lua although I don't know the syntax of it. Do you know why Lua is so used in gamedev? I've seen it used many times, dunno why

Comment: 1: GDB is not "simple" for "simple" stuff. You can debug almost anything, even injected machine code. (I am actually doing this currently while working on a JIT compiler.) You might want to read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GDB#Features - There have been books published about it, because it is anything but simple. ;) --- 2: You can add extensions to your program using Lua very quickly. (Aka "Mods")

Comment: Upvote for Lua. I've used it with a simple OpenGL app and it did what I needed in that case (simple user-editable functions for generating motion).

Comment: @RahulBanerjee that's cool Rahul. Can you throw your code on github so I can have a look ? Thanks

Comment: Just forgot: For a little "By-example"-Overview of Lua this page is a good start: http://cc.byexamples.com/2008/06/07/how-to-embed-lua-51-in-c

Comment: @jojo modjo: Sorry, I wrote that 3+ years ago, on some computer I no longer have access to... But the link posted right above (how to embed lua) is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

i can´t help with the questions if it´s a good or bad idea.

but you could take a look at [Chaiscript](http://chaiscript.com/) that´s really easy to use with c++

Answer (score 0):

Python is a very good choice as application scripting language. Its not a strong argument but I know that [lua](http://www.lua.org/) is widely used in game programming (I d'ont know why), it may be useful since you are using OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

Use **lua** - it's simple stack based interpreter. With very clean API.

E.g.: [Simple code that add dt_format|dt_convert functions to lua](http://libdms.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/libdms/libdms4/luas/utils/lua_utils.cxx?revision=1.1&view=markup)